# c# Superposed control doesn't fire events

Tags: c#, winforms, events

My Windows Forms code has two superposed PictureBoxes: a small X on the top corner of a user-loaded image. I'll call them DelImage and Image, respectively. Like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltLO8.jpg

The DelImage appears (`Visible = true`) on `Image_MouseEnter` and disappears on `Image_MouseLeave`. Now, I want the DelImage to have a custom behavior as well when the mouse enters it, but DelImage never fires events (nor `MouseEnter`, nor `MouseLeave`, nor `Click`). I've tried bringing it to front, but it already is in front of the Image.

Here's some code:

```
private void picImage_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    delImage.Visible = true;
}

private void picImage_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    delImage.Visible = false;
}

private void picDelImage_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    delImage.Visible = true;
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}

private void picDelImage_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
}

private void picDelImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel currentPanel = this.tlpImages.Controls["pnlImage"] as Panel;
    currentPanel.Visible = false;
}
```

With this code, the picDelImage events are never reached. I never enter DelImage, apparently because I never leave Image. What can I do to make my PictureBoxes have the expected behavior?

Comment: Does `picDelImage` disappear when you enter its position? I suppose entering `picDelImage` first executes `picImage_MouseLeave` and this method makes `picDelImage` invisible.

Comment: If I'm already inside Image and then enter DelImage, it doesn't disappear (doesn't run `picImage_MouseLeave`). That's what I mean when I say that I never enter DelImage because I never leave Image. If I'm out of everything and enter directly DelImage (through the top-right corner of Image), it doesn't appear (but its borders do).

Comment: It took me all this time to understand what you were saying, @MatthiasG... you're right and I'm dumb. Sorry for that haha
I'll try a different approach.